# Variadic concept constraints

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

Unfortunately this code doesn't work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <tuple>

template<typename FirstArg, typename ... Args>
    requires (sizeof ... (Args) == 0 || (std::is_convertible_v<Args ..., FirstArg>))
constexpr void multi_max( FirstArg firstArg, Args const &... args )
{
    using namespace std;
    FirstArg &max = firstArg;
    auto findMax = [&]<size_t ... Is>( index_sequence<Is ...> iseq, tuple<Args ...> tArgs )
    {
        ((max = get<Is>( tArgs ) > max ? get<Is>( tArgs ) : max), ...);
    };
    findMax( make_index_sequence<sizeof ... (Args)>(), make_tuple( args ... ) );
}

int main()
{
    multi_max( 1 );
    //multi_max( 1, 2, 3 );
}
```

The commented section doesn't fulfill the right half of the requires-constraint. Why ? And if I remove the first constraint the compilers complains about wrong unpacking of the args into a tuple.

Answer (score 6):

Looking at the relevant portion of the compiler error:

> note: because substituted constraint expression is ill-formed: too many template arguments for variable template 'is_convertible_v'

You're using `is_convertible_v<int, int, int>`. What you want is *all* tests of individual arguments to be true, which you can do with a fold expression:

```
requires (sizeof ... (Args) == 0 || (std::is_convertible_v<Args, FirstArg> && ...))
```

However, for a pack of 0 elements, the fold expression will produce `true` for `&&`, so the first part is now redundant:

```
requires (std::is_convertible_v<Args, FirstArg> && ...)
```

Cleaning up to use the concept `convertible_to` instead of the old type trait:

```
requires (std::convertible_to<Args, FirstArg> && ...)
```

Now things are looking a little suspiciously convenient. We can actually move this to the template parameter and get rid of the `requires` entirely:

```
template<typename FirstArg, std::convertible_to<FirstArg> ... Args>
```

This *placeholder* will shove `FirstArg` in as the second argument and place the given type as the first, so a given `T` would test `std::convertible_to<T, FirstArg>`.